# How to do series expansion for functions which have symbolic parameters?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I would like to find the series expansion of

```
    (E^(x^k/k!) Gamma[k, x])/Gamma[k]
```

for $k$ being a positive integer, up to the order of $x^{2k+1}$. Mathematica provides a function `Series`, which can deal with this when $k$ is replaced by any *fixed* integers. But it cannot handle the case $k$ remains a symbol.

Is it actually possible to get this for general $k$ in Mathematica?

Comment: Note that this function can be expressed as `E^(x^k/k!) GammaRegularized[k, x]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, this can be done in such a way:

```
Expand[Normal[Series[Exp[y], {y, 0, 2}]] /. y -> x^k/k!*
Normal[Series[Gamma[k, x]/Gamma[k], {x, 0, 2}, 
  Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers && k > 0]]]
```

> $$\frac{x^{4 k}}{2 k^2 (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)^2}+\frac{x^{2 k}}{2 (k!)^2}-\frac{x^{2 k}}{k k! \Gamma (k)}-\frac{x^{3 k}}{k (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)}+\frac{x^{2 k+1}}{(k+1) k! \Gamma (k)}-\frac{x^{2 k+2}}{2 (k+2) k! \Gamma (k)}+\frac{x^{3 k+1}}{(k+1) (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)}-\frac{x^{3 k+2}}{2 (k+2) (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)}-\frac{x^{4 k+1}}{k (k+1) (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)^2}+\frac{x^{4 k+2}}{2 (k+1)^2 (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)^2}+\frac{x^{4 k+2}}{2 k (k+2) (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)^2}-\frac{x^{4 k+3}}{2 (k+1) (k+2) (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)^2}+\frac{x^{4 k+4}}{8 (k+2)^2 (k!)^2 \Gamma (k)^2}+\frac{x^k}{k!}+1 $$

Increasing the order of the power series expansion (two in the above), one obtains a huge expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different method for doing it:

```
ode = First[Head[DifferentialRootReduce[GammaRegularized[k, x], x]]];

ser = Normal[Series[Exp[z], {z, 0, 3}]] /. z -> x^k/k!;

ser2 = FullSimplify[AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode[y, x], y[x], {x, 0, 3}]];

Assuming[k > 0, Expand[FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[ser ser2]]]]
   1 + x^(1 + k)/((1 + k) Gamma[k]) - x^(2 + k)/(2 (2 + k) Gamma[k]) +
   x^(3 + k)/(6 (3 + k) Gamma[k]) - x^(4 k)/(6 Gamma[1 + k]^4) +
   (k x^(1 + 4 k))/(6 (1 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^4) -
   (k x^(2 + 4 k))/(12 (2 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^4) +
   (k x^(3 + 4 k))/(36 (3 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^4) - x^(3 k)/(3 Gamma[1 + k]^3) +
   (k x^(1 + 3 k))/(2 (1 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^3) -
   (k x^(2 + 3 k))/(4 (2 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^3) +
   (k x^(3 + 3 k))/(12 (3 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^3) - x^(2 k)/(2 Gamma[1 + k]^2) +
   (k x^(1 + 2 k))/((1 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^2) -
   (k x^(2 + 2 k))/(2 (2 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^2) +
   (k x^(3 + 2 k))/(6 (3 + k) Gamma[1 + k]^2)
```